# ASP.NET Core 2.1: How to copy (or find) a file when running integration tests?

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-2.1

We have a manually updated json file in our project, it is found under
`%solutionDir%/SomeProject/SomeProject/Foo.json`

We are writing an integration test to perform some check on this static json file (so we can determine if it has been updated manually, incorrectly, or if it should have been updated, but hasn't).

Our integration test project is under `%solutionDir%/SomeProject/SomeProject.IntegrationTests/`

We reference the Foo.json file via

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\SomeProject\Foo.json" Link="Foo.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

When building the test project, we see the file is output to our `/bin` folder.

When trying to reference the file in our test method via `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`, we are unable to find the file, as the integration test runs in a different (`.../AppData/.../Temp/...`) folder, with only a dll file in it.

How can I reference the json file that we are copying over to the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when running locally, using `var location = System.AppContext.BaseDirectory` will give the correct folder, then using `Path.Combine(location, "Swagger.json");` gives us the file.

Not sure if this is the recommended approach, but it works for now.